# What ** means in Gradle Copy task

Tags: file, copy, gradle

Hi I don't fully understand the hole conception of ** in Gradle copy task. For example

```
task copyPoems(type: Copy) {
 from 'text-files'
 into 'build/poems'
 include '**/sh*.txt'
}
```

What is the difference of include with and without **.

Answer (score 4):

The '**' means to include subdirectories

```
include '**/sh*.txt'  // include all sh*.txt files in 'text-files' and any subdirectory

include 'sh*.txt'  // include all sh*.txt files in only the one directory (eg, 'text-files')
```

By the way, the usage is EXACTLY the same way the ant tool uses it, since the API is the same.