# Playing with the Copy task in Gradle 3.0

Tags: gradle, task, build.gradle

I have a folder called android. Inside it there are two empty subfolders called acitivities and fragments. I want to copy in the fragments folder the FragmentA.txt,FragmentB.txt,and inside the activities folder the MainActivity txt.

[image: task forder]

I know that I have to use something like this.

```
task copyFragments(type: Copy){
   from: '...'
   into  '...'
}
```

but i don't know how to only select the FragmentA and FragmentB.txt files to copy them.

I tried this:

```
task copyFragments(type: Copy){
from 'android' {
  include '*.txt'
  into android/fragments
  }


}
```

but it doesn't work. I get an error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'FoldersTasks'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments   
[build_17yr8758ttz6pq3odf7qrpm5b$_run_closure1$_closure2@67cb2a83] on task    
':copyFragments' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --  
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What \*\* means in Gradle Copy task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217397/what-means-in-gradle-copy-task)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
task copyFragments(type: Copy){
   from file('android')
   include 'Fragment*'
   into  'activities'
}
```